# Queue implementation without using built-in data structures

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, queue, circular-list

In an effort to brush up my algorithms and data structure skills I have a done a queue implementation without using built in data structures, i.e. using only arrays. Any comments on this code regarding issues, bad/ good practices and good style would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class QueueError : public std::runtime_error {
    public:
        QueueError(std::string str) : std::runtime_error(str) {};
};

class Queue {
    struct LLNode {
        int val;
        LLNode* next;
    };
    private:
        LLNode** queue = 0;
        int limit;
        int currSize = 0;
        LLNode* first;
        LLNode* last;
        void swap(const Queue& that);
        void destroy();
    public:
        Queue(int size);
        void enqueue(int val);
        int dequeue();
        virtual ~Queue();
        Queue& operator=(const Queue& that);
        Queue(const Queue& that);
        int size();

};

Queue::Queue(int size) {
    if (size <= 0) throw QueueError("Queue size cannot be negative or 0");
    this->limit = size;
    const int l = this->limit;
    queue = new LLNode*[l];
    // make it circular
    for (int i = 0;i < l; ++i) {
        queue[i] = new LLNode();
        if ((i - 1) >= 0) {
            queue[i-1]->next = queue[i];
        }
    }
    queue[l-1]->next = queue[0];
    first = 0;
    last = 0;
}

void Queue::enqueue(int val) {
    if (currSize == limit) {
        throw QueueError(std::string("Queue size cannot exceed limit of queue."));
    }
    ++currSize;
    if (last != 0) {
        last = last->next;
    } else {
        first = last = queue[0];
    }
    last->val = val;
}

int Queue::dequeue() {
    if (currSize == 0) {
        throw QueueError(std::string("Queue size is 0. Queue cannot be dequeued"));
    }
    currSize--;
    int returnVal = first->val;
    if (currSize != 0) {
        first = first->next;
    } else {
        first = last = 0;
    }
    return returnVal;
}

int Queue::size() {
    return currSize;
}

void Queue::destroy() {
    if (queue == 0) return;
    const int l = this->limit;
    for (int i = 0;i < l; ++i) {
        delete queue[i];
    }
    delete[] queue;
}

Queue::~Queue() {
    destroy();
}

void Queue::swap(const Queue& that) {
    this->limit = that.limit;
    const int l = this->limit;
    LLNode** tmpQueue = new LLNode*[l];
    // make it circular
    for (int i = 0;i < l; ++i) {
        tmpQueue[i] = new LLNode();
        tmpQueue[i]->val = that.queue[i]->val;
        if ((i - 1) >= 0) {
            tmpQueue[i-1]->next = tmpQueue[i];
        }
    }
    tmpQueue[l-1]->next = tmpQueue[0];
    destroy();
    queue = tmpQueue;
    first = that.first;
    last = that.last;
    currSize = that.currSize;
}

Queue::Queue(const Queue& that) {
    swap(that);
}

Queue& Queue::operator=(const Queue& that) {
    if (this != &that) {
        Queue tmp(that);
        swap(tmp);
    }
    return *this;
}



int main() {
    const int qSize = 200;
    const int addVal = 100;
    Queue queue(qSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < qSize; ++i) {
        queue.enqueue(i + addVal);
        //std::cout << i + addVal << " ";
    }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    assert(queue.size() == qSize);
    // make a copy
    Queue queueCopy = queue;

    // check if exception is thrown
    bool exThrown = false;
    try {
        queue.enqueue(100);
    } catch (QueueError &e) {
        exThrown = true;
    }
    assert(exThrown);

    for (int i = 0; i < qSize; ++i) {
        int val = queue.dequeue();
        //std::cout << val << " ";
        assert(val == (i + addVal));
    }

    exThrown = false;
    try {
        queue.dequeue();
    } catch (QueueError &e) {
        exThrown = true;
    }
    assert(exThrown);

    // can I enqueue again?
    queue.enqueue(addVal);
    assert(queue.dequeue() == addVal);

    // check Copy
    for (int i = 0; i < qSize; ++i) {
        int val = queueCopy.dequeue();
        assert(val == (i + addVal));
    }
    std::cout << "All queue tests run successfully" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thing I would change is the ordering of fields in the class declaration. I find it better to place **public** fields first, since this is what users of the class are interested on, most of the time. Then place **protected** fields in the sequence, since these are externally accessible via inheritance, so their encapsulation is less strong. Lastly place **private** fields that are only important to the class maintainer.

---

Unnecessary virtual destructor: Don't make a destructor `virtual` unless you intend to extend the class. In this case, I don't see why anyone would want to extend a queue implementation. Any use or extension of the queue can be done with composition, which is generally preferred over inheritance.

---

Default initialize all fields, not just some. Do it either in the declaration or in the constructor.

```
LLNode** queue = nullptr;
LLNode* first  = nullptr;
LLNode* last   = nullptr;
int limit      = 0;
int currSize   = 0;
```

Also notice the use of [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) for the pointers. This is the standard since C++11.

---

Methods that don't mutate member state should be `const`. `size()` is an example:

```
int size() const;
```

---

Instead of returning the removed element in `int dequeue()`, perhaps provide a `int front() const` method that returns the element without removing. Then make `dequeue()` void. This is the interface of `std::queue`, so it would be a good idea to somewhat follow the convention people are most used to.

---

You don't need that explicit string cast when throwing the exceptions:

```
throw QueueError(std::string("Queue size is 0. Queue cannot be dequeued"));
```

All that is doing is creating an extra copy of the string. Some compilers might not be smart enough to optimize that out. It should be just:

```
throw QueueError("Queue size is 0. Queue cannot be dequeued");
```

---

If you separate your code into header file and `.cpp` implementation, make sure to only leave the necessary includes in the header file. You don't have to include `<cassert>` and `<iostream>` in the header, just in the `.cpp`. Being careful with your includes will help you keeping compile times under control.

Comment: +1, but I think your first point is just personal preference. Listing `private` then `public` is perfectly fine in my eyes.

Comment: The reason why `pop_back` & co do not return the value is not style or convention but exception safety. Supposedly it is not possible to make `T pop_back();` exception safe, but I couldn't go into detail on that.

Comment: @Yuushi - Yes, you could say so. But I did give a reason for that preference. So it wasn't just randomly picked `;)`

Comment: @nwp - Well, yes, it makes sense. The constructor of `T` can throw. When removing from the container, a temp copy inside `pop()` would be almost certain. Which could affect the validity of the container if an exception happens in mid removal.

Comment: You make some good points. Thank you for that. But, I'm wondering about point 1 and 2. The first one seems to be more of a preference through. I prefer my fields in the order of private, protected and public. Also, isn't it better to make the destructor virtual in case the class is extended?

Comment: @dev_nut - Yes the first point is mainly from personal experience and preference. That ordering seems more reader-friendly to me for the reasons I mentioned. My main reason to advocate against the virtual destrutor is the [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it) principle. I also recommend reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353817/should-every-class-have-a-virtual-destructor) threads.

Answer (score 5):

1. It's quite strange that you have this indirection via `LLNode` - you effectively have a linked list and an array at the same time. This seems like double work. I would get rid of `LLNode` and just go via the index into the array. This gets rid of a whole lot of code (or get rid of the array and use a linked list instead).

   Queues are a natural fit for linked lists as you typically only access the head and tail and don't need random access. Although most standard library queue implementations I know of are array based probably due to better performance (cache locality)
2. It shouldn't be too hard to template the item type so you can have a queue of any type rather than just `int`.

Comment: I guess I had mixed ideas and made a little mess here. I initially was trying to just use an array, and thought I can't do that, I need a linked list. I see I'm wrong here. Thanks for pointing this out.